# Magento2: So close, but Admin won't run

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0

Magento2 has installed successfully. At least IT says so. Calling the localhost domain launches the website properly and everything there looks good. However, when I run localhost/admin I get a 404.

Every iteration of the URL returns the same result (/Admin /admin /Admin/ or /admin/)

The install is dev alpha-101 and the entire install process progressed without error or warning.

Is there a file mod I need to make to allow the admin app to run? I can't figure out why the regular website runs, but the admin app does not.

Any pointers greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried `/backend/admin` instead?

Comment: Yes. Same 404 error.

Answer (score 1):

Solved this issue.

Turns out when I ran the installer, I included a '/' after the word admin when I was entering the URL for the admin area, which was in turn written to the local.xml file.

So, I went back to the local.xml file, removed the offending '/', and then reloaded the URL, everything just worked.

Hilarious.

Good news is I have Magento2 running locally on Yosemite without MAMP. I did my own AMP stack and everything plays nicely for now.